# Add a <br> html tag to WooCommerce checkout radio buttons form field options

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, radio-button

**Before the update of woocommerce:**

```
   $args = array(
   'type' => 'radio',
   'class' => array( 'form-row-wide', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
   'options' => array(
      '0'   => 'Niet vandaag, misschien later (totally oké) <br />',
      '2'   => 'Drinkt iets van mij (€2) <br />',
      '3'   => 'Van mij krijgt ge een bio thee\'tje (€3) <br />',
      '5'   => 'Vier ze! Ik schenk je een Kombucha (€5)',
   ),
   'label_class' => 'labelafter',
   'default' => $chosen
   );
     
   echo '<div id="checkout-radio">';
   echo '<h3>Wil je mij virtueel trakteren?</h3>';
   woocommerce_form_field( 'radio_choice', $args, $chosen );
   echo '</div>';
```

My radio buttons showed up vertically aligned on my website checkout page

**After the update**
The same code now *shows* the '<br />' (in the radio button option list on line 5) tag and does not convert the '<br />' tag to an *actual* line break.

I've got no clue why wordpress is suddently showing the tag iso converting it.
Anyone got an idea?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/369849/woocommerce-form-field-function-having-issues-after-latest-woocommerce-updat

Comment: Thanks. That was quick. 
So esc_html is causing the issue. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I have no idea, this is my first time learning about it

Comment: Okay - thanks.
Now I've got at least some direction to look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For custom checkout radio buttons fields, you can use `woocommerce_form_field_radio` composite hook to add a `<br />` tag like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_form_field_radio', 'customize_form_field_radio', 20, 4 );
function customize_form_field_radio( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    if ( ! empty( $args['options'] ) && 'radio_choice' === $key && is_checkout() ) {
        $field = str_replace( '</label><input ', '</label><br /><input ', $field );
        $field = str_replace( '<label ', '<label style="display:inline;margin-left:8px;" ', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Don't forget to remove all `<br />` from your options array.

So the display will be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Works exactly as before the update, so that's awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd probably solve this in CSS instead, by just targeting them an applying a `display:block` on each field.

But otherwise you can apply a bit of hack. Instead of an HTML `<br />` tag, use some string that you know will never exist in any radio button fields, and that is HTML-safe, and replace it in a filter with your `<br />`;

```php
// Pick something you know won't exist
$lineBreakHack = '~!LINE-BREAK!~';

// Woo will call this hook for all radio buttons, not just yours, but that shouldn't be too much of a perf issue
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_form_field_radio',
    function($field, $key, $args, $value){
        return str_replace($lineBreakHack, '<br />', $field);
    }
);

// This is mostly the same except we're concatenating our special string
$args = array(
'type' => 'radio',
    'class' => array( 'form-row-wide', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
    'options' => array(
      '0'   => 'Niet vandaag, misschien later (totally oké)' . $lineBreakHack,
      '2'   => 'Drinkt iets van mij (€2) <br />' . $lineBreakHack,
      '3'   => 'Van mij krijgt ge een bio thee\'tje (€3)' . $lineBreakHack,
      '5'   => 'Vier ze! Ik schenk je een Kombucha (€5)',
    ),
    'label_class' => 'labelafter',
    'default' => $chosen
);
```

Comment: You just beat me to this question LOL! I was about to submit an answer using the css approach. Anyways you're right. Nice hack!

Comment: @Ruvee, if you have the specific CSS, I'd totally up-vote that because that's what I'd recommend, too. I just didn't have time to figure out the most-proper selector for this scenario.

Comment: It's very nice of you, thank you sir. i was about to recommend the same css approach. It was just funny that you beat me to it lol. I like your hack too.

Comment: Thanks! 
This also does the trick.

And I know that the ideally it should be done via CSS, but couldn't figure that one out either :')